# Stacks, Queue, Deque - When to use what?

Tags: java, queue, deque

I apologize in advance if this question is too simple or already answered. I could not find any similar questions here on stackoverflow, nor could I find useful information online.

I am currently dealing with stack/queue/deque. I know how they act (LIFO, FIFO, and then deques does it both) but I am struggling to find out the purpose.

- What could these 3 ADTs possibly be used for?
- Can one of them be used over another for a better result? I'm thinking that it would be smart to just always use deque, since it offers the same methods as queue and stack - am I wrong?
- What about performance (as in speed)? Anything that needs to be taken into consideration when using them?

Comment: At the most basic level (using these directly) I wouldn't use a deque in place of a queue or stack. Using either in place of a stack means you can never depend on it being a stack. Anyone can corrupt a stack's definition providing them with dangerous functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Stacks/Queues are basic data structures that are used in various computer science fields like in Operating systems, Computer Networking.

Operation like LIFO,FIFO etc. are used on various occasion depending on the purpose of task like in graph(another data structure), while implementing BFS uses queue to store nodes which further uses basic operation like FIFO.

And, yes speed matters. But, we also need to take care of memory constraints.

P.S. These data structures and their operation may seem irrelevant but as you study further you will realise that many great algorithms are based on these itself.